# What's the ffmpeg command to extract PPM files from an existing video?

Tags: ffmpeg

What's the ffmpeg command to extract PPM (or Portable Pix Map) files from an existing video?

Like the reverse of this https://askubuntu.com/questions/971119/convert-a-sequence-of-ppm-images-to-avi-video

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output_%04d.ppm
```

Output files will be named `output_0001.ppm`, `output_0002.ppm`, etc. See the [image muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2) for more options and info.